# Is there a Hot Key to refresh the stored procedures in SQL 2008 r2?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

We have a ton of Stored Procedures. Every time I add a new one, I have to go all the way to the top of the stored procedures and right click and hit "Refresh". It is there a hot key to refresh the Tables and Stored Procedures list?  I have googled everywhere.  Did MS think developers where only going to have a few of each?  I know this sounds trivial but it's a pain in the butt when you are creating many stored procedures and constantly have to scroll to the top and hit refresh before you can pull it up to execute it to test it. I am using SQL 2008 R2.

Comment: F5 not working when you are on the list?

Comment: As far as I know there is no quick or easy way to refresh.  You can use [RedGate SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/) (which is free) to quickly locate procedures.  The function is "select object in object explorer"

Comment: @Oded: If you have a procedure selected, F5 only refreshes the selected procedure.  It won't add or delete procedures

Comment: You could execute it by writing the code to do it, you can even grab the create proc line as a template for the parameters.

Comment: It's one of those windows programs that does not even follow MS's own standards F5 doesn't refresh at this point (kinda dumb on MS's behalf).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no keyboard shortcut to refresh the list. However, arrow-left gets you to the parent node. So if you have a procedure highlighted, pressing arrow-left followed by F5 will refresh the procedures. But then you still have to find the new one again.

Answer (score 1):

There is no shortcut to refresh the procedure list from the query window.

Here is a list of SQL Server Management Studio's Shortcut list:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174205.aspx

However, if you don't want to right click refresh, and just use the keyboard you can do the following:

```
1. Create your procedure

2. ALT-F8 (This will navigate your selection to your object explorer window, and highlight your connected server)

3. Start typing the first letter of the database you are working in. This will highlight that database. Use the right arrow to expand, if not already expanded.

4. Then type P for Programmability, and that will highlight that list. Again, use the right arrow to expand if not already expanded.

5. Then type S for Stored Procedures. 

6. Hit F5, and it will refresh your list.
```

**Another way is you could simply hit ALT F8, and use your arrow keys to navigate to your node, and then hit F5 to refresh.**

Granted this is the LONG way to doing it. It may be easier to use your mouse. However, if you are working on a server that does not have a mouse, keyboard navigation is essential.

Comment: Yup, it's easier just to scroll a couple hundred lines :(